# How good is the suggested add missing index(es) in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server

We've been using the **Include Actual Execution Plan** feature quite a bit in SSMS to optimize our queries. Sometimes it will recommend we add an index. I'm curious how good/accurate this recommendation is. For example, if I'm analyzing a query and there are no indexes it suggests should be added, am I safe in assuming no additional index could possible improve performance?

If this is not the case, are there better tools available that will tell us indexes that should be added (or other optimizations that could be made)?

We're using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: It makes me so sad that StackExchange closes questions like this. Is it interesting? Yes. Is it useful? Yes. Are they running out of space? Why is something opinion based not interesting to have on a page on the internet?! I'd love to be able to use StackExchange as a recommendation as well as an answer engine! :'(

Comment: This doesn't look like an opinion based post. It's clearly asking how reliable a feature is on Sql Server and which other tools are available that perform the same task.

Comment: @CarlosH - Doesn't really matter. SO is pretty messed up and some people here are way to intense and hyper.

Answer (score 5):

In general, never use an index suggested by this feature untested. Those indexes only look at that one query and do not take the entire workload into consideration. Also, they often are overloaded with columns that are not necessary to improve performance.

A missing index warning is a good indication that an additional index would improve performance. However, use them as a starting point only. Always review to make sure they make sense and make sure there is no other index that would make more sense.

Some people recommend the database tuning advisor. It looks at the total workload before making recommendations. But even there I would prefer a manual review or at least a good performance test before applying them to production.

Comment: In addition, I would add that you should also be careful not to duplicate indexes.  The index recommendations do not account for like indexes that already exist.  Majority of the time, I find that the index that is being recommended already exists, but is missing a column in the key or include list.  In those cases, I would evaluate adding those columns to the existing index.